# Resize image without aspect ratio in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, imagemagick

I need resize image to fixed size in Node.js through ImageMagick. Example: images 200x140, 500x200 and 130x100 converted to 100x50. The image must be stretched or compressed without aspect ratio and fill the entire space. I do this so:

```
var im = require('imagemagick');

var resize_options = {
    srcPath: path,
    dstPath: path,
    width: 100,
    height: 50
};
im.resize(resize_options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.end('Error!');
    }
    else {
        res.end('Success!');
    }
});
```

But image converten by only height, example - 1440x900 converted to 80x50 instead 100x50. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See if there is a `replaceExact` method which only takes output size parameters, or if you can slip in an exclamation mark amongst options. Please read documentation for [`gm`](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) on github - it covers this issue exactly. Noting the `imagemagick` module is abandoned in favor of `gm`. If this solves your issue please post an answer describing how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var im = require('imagemagick');

var width = 800;
var height = 123;
im.convert(['./in.jpg', '-resize', width + 'x' + height + '\!', './out.png'],
  function (err, stdout) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

would do the job. It resizes your image independantly of its original size to the given width & height

Answer (score 0):

Using Sascha's answer, in case someone searches for this, you can use strings in the options and specify the exclamation point on the height as follows

```
var resize_options = {
    srcPath: path,
    dstPath: path,
    width: "100",
    height: "50!",
};
```